# Update Aptana Studio 3 with latest PyDev

Tags: python, windows-vista, pydev, aptana3

OS is Windoze Vista, 32 bit

Aptana Studio 3.4.2 installs PyDev 2.7.0.

How do I install PyDev 2.8.2?

I went to `Help>Install New Software` and added the site http://pydev.org/updates, checked 'Show only latest versions …' and 'Group items by category', pressed 'Next' and got the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
    Software being installed: PyDev for Eclipse 2.8.2.2013090511 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.8.2.2013090511)
    Software currently installed: Aptana Studio 3 3.4.2.201308081805-08082013180610 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.4.2.201308081805-08082013180610)
    Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
        Core Plug-in 1.5.5.2010030420 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.5.2010030420)
        Core Plug-in 2.3.0.2011121518 (org.python.pydev.core 2.3.0.2011121518)
        Core Plug-in 1.6.1.2010080312 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.1.2010080312)
        Core Plug-in 2.2.2.2011082312 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.2.2011082312)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.1.1258496115 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.1.1258496115)
        Core Plug-in 2.7.5.2013052819 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.5.2013052819)
        Core Plug-in 2.7.1.2012100913 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.1.2012100913)
        Core Plug-in 1.6.3.2010100513 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.3.2010100513)
        Core Plug-in 2.2.3.2011100616 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.3.2011100616)
        Core Plug-in 2.2.4.2011110216 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.4.2011110216)
        Core Plug-in 2.6.0.2012062818 (org.python.pydev.core 2.6.0.2012062818)
        Core Plug-in 2.2.1.2011071313 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.1.2011071313)
        Core Plug-in 2.8.1.2013072611 (org.python.pydev.core 2.8.1.2013072611)
        Core Plug-in 2.1.0.2011052613 (org.python.pydev.core 2.1.0.2011052613)
        Core Plug-in 2.7.3.2013031601 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.3.2013031601)
        Core Plug-in 1.6.2.2010090711 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.2.2010090711)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.7.2010050621 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.7.2010050621)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.2.1260362205 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.2.1260362205)
        Core Plug-in 2.0.0.2011040403 (org.python.pydev.core 2.0.0.2011040403)
        Core Plug-in 2.7.4.2013051601 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.4.2013051601)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.8.2010062823 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.8.2010062823)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.0.1251989166 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.0.1251989166)
        Core Plug-in 2.7.0.2012100419 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.0.2012100419)
        Core Plug-in 1.6.0.2010071813 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.0.2010071813)
        Core Plug-in 1.6.4.2011010200 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.4.2011010200)
        Core Plug-in 2.5.0.2012040618 (org.python.pydev.core 2.5.0.2012040618)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.6.2010033101 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.6.2010033101)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.9.2010063001 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.9.2010063001)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.9.2010063000 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.9.2010063000)
        Core Plug-in 1.6.5.2011020317 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.5.2011020317)
        Core Plug-in 2.8.0.2013072518 (org.python.pydev.core 2.8.0.2013072518)
        Core Plug-in 1.6.2.2010090812 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.2.2010090812)
        Core Plug-in 2.7.2.2013031501 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.2.2013031501)
        Core Plug-in 2.2.0.2011062419 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.0.2011062419)
        Core Plug-in 2.8.2.2013090511 (org.python.pydev.core 2.8.2.2013090511)
        Core Plug-in 2.7.0.2013032300 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.0.2013032300)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.4.2010011921 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.4.2010011921)
        Core Plug-in 2.4.0.2012020116 (org.python.pydev.core 2.4.0.2012020116)
        Core Plug-in 1.5.3.1260479439 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.3.1260479439)
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: Aptana Studio 3 RCP 3.4.2.201308081805-7o7nFDFFFcLz-2l0rkQ0UYz0u_Wm (com.aptana.feature.rcp.feature.group 3.4.2.201308081805-7o7nFDFFFcLz-2l0rkQ0UYz0u_Wm)
        To: com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group [3.4.2.201308081736-7W7I57boG98RAi489ctbvKi7VXbq]
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.4.2.201308081736-7W7I57boG98RAi489ctbvKi7VXbq (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.4.2.201308081736-7W7I57boG98RAi489ctbvKi7VXbq)
        To: com.aptana.pydev.feature.feature.group [2.7.0.2013032300-7g9I-8Jez0cfdJcee]
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: Aptana Pydev 2.7.0.2013032300-7g9I-8Jez0cfdJcee (com.aptana.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.7.0.2013032300-7g9I-8Jez0cfdJcee)
        To: org.python.pydev.core [2.7.0.2013032300]
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: Aptana Studio 3 3.4.2.201308081805-08082013180610 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.4.2.201308081805-08082013180610)
        To: com.aptana.feature.rcp.feature.group [3.4.2.201308081805-7o7nFDFFFcLz-2l0rkQ0UYz0u_Wm]
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
```

Next, I went to my `AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\plugins` directory & replaced all PyDev 2.7.0 files with the 2.8.2 set.  When I opened Aptana I got a `Could not open the editor: No editor descriptor for id org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor` error.

I had heard that you can only do PyDev when installing Aptana, so I tried to extract the Aptana setup file `Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.4.2.exe` and replace those PyDev 2.7.0 files with the 2.8.2 set, but I couldn't find anything that looked familiar, so I left it be.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why am I being voted down on this?

Comment: sandrstar: Your comment is irrelevant. I think the question is sincere and deserves an upvote because it's such a common problem to anyone using pydev with eclipse (or Aptana). This is a type of question that someone who works as a computer programmer would reasonably want to know and your comment (and/or downvote) is neither helpful nor constructive.

Comment: It would be awesome to easily update PyDev on Aptana. This question has been asked a while ago, has anybody succeeded in doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aptana has it own pydev installed because of its internal dependencies, so it is not safe to update it and you have to wait Aptana team to release a new version of the software. 
If you want to be more flexible and update all the parts you need, just use plain Eclipse with all the plugins you need installed.(pydev, html, javascript, css and so on...)

Answer (score 1):

There's an hack to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971061/398491

Basically you can install a beta version of Aptana in order to uninstall PyDev and then install the latest PyDev through the update site.