# Anaconda Python and PyDev (in Aptana Studio)

Tags: python, ipython, pydev

I have just updated my installation of `Python 3.4` using `Anaconda`.
I am now unable to open a `PyDev console` in `Aptana Studio` using this version of Python, although I can use a different version of Python.

The error message I get is this:

```
Error initializing console.
Unexpected error connecting to console.
Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: Console already exited with value: 1 while waiting for an answer.
Error stream: C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\traitlets.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
  warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
Error starting server with host: 127.0.0.1, port: 52021, client_port: 52022
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472\pysrc\pydevconsole.py", line 222, in <module>
    StartServer(pydev_localhost.get_localhost(), int(port), int(client_port))
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472\pysrc\pydevconsole.py", line 191, in StartServer
    interpreter = InterpreterInterface(host, client_port, server)
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472\pysrc\pydev_ipython_console.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.interpreter = PyDevFrontEnd(pydev_host=host, pydev_client_port=client_port)
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472\pysrc\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.ipython = PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell.instance()
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 396, in __init__
    super(TerminalInteractiveShell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 495, in __init__
    self.init_completer()
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472\pysrc\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 220, in init_completer
    self.Completer = self._new_completer_200()
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472\pysrc\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 192, in _new_completer_200
    use_readline=self.has_readline,
AttributeError: 'PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'has_readline'
```

I have been following other threads and getting contradictory information about 32 and 64 bit compatibility. I am running `64-bit Win7`. I now have both 64 bit and 32 bit versions of `Java` installed. `Aptana` only exists as 32 bit for Windows, and I think it uses the `32 bit`Java, as `Aptana` would not initialise when I only had `64 bit Java` installed. I have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of `Anaconda`, with the same result.
I have tried updating ipython. 
I have also tried changing the proxy settings to manual and selecting 127.0.0.1 and local host. 
I have run out of ideas!

Comment: Following advice from other threads, I have tried the following:
1)  updated ipython
2) Changed the proxy settings in Aptana to manual and selected both 127.0.0.1 and local host
- with no improvement.

Comment: I have now installed a 32-bit version of Anaconda and pointed Aptana to taht version of Python. Same result.

Comment: I also wonder if the issue is with teh latest version of ipython (as in this similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814560/disable-ipython-console-in-pycharm) but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Yes, that is something that changed in IPython 5. PyDev 3.0 is quite old (PyDev [is on 5.3 now](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/)). Can you try updating the PyDev plugin? Or maybe you need to update Aptana as a whole; I'm not familiar with how it handles plugins.

Comment: Thank you. That's useful. But it seems Aptana does not allow you to update PyDev. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819954/update-aptana-studio-3-with-latest-pydev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall Aptana.
Install PyCharm.
Simples.

Comment: Unfortunately, Aptana uses an ancient version of PyDev, so, if you use a newer Eclipse+PyDev (or LiClipse which bundles Eclipse and PyDev by default), things will work properly (i.e.: this was an issue with compatibility of that old PyDev version and IPython 5).